# Killing a goroutine once theres a new value in a channel

Tags: go, channel, goroutine

For each new value in a channel, a goroutine spawns. When there's a new value in a channel, I want a new goroutine to start, and the old one to be killed. I suspect that my code is killing the new goroutine and keeping the first one alive. how can I fix this?

```
func Start() {
    go func() {
        quit := make(chan bool, 1)
        for nbp := range poll() {
            quit <- true
            go create(nbp, quit)
        }
    }()
}

func create(nbp map[string]string, , quit chan bool) {
    for {
        select {
        case <-quit:
            fmt.Println("quiting this goroutine!")
            return
        default:
            for k, v := range nbp {
            ...
            }
            time.Sleep(3 * time.Second)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: because your channel is buffered, you can push the first item without blocking, thus, when the routinee is spawned at `go create(nbp, quit)` it enters the select and find a value in the quit channel. Thus, it quits....

Comment: When I remove the 1 from the buffer, nothing happens...

Comment: yes, it blocks waiting for something to read it.

Comment: Mind if I just ask: Why? channels and routines are a great tool to offload some work to be done concurrently. If you wait for a new value on the channel, kill a routine and start the exact same routine in its place, why not simply keep the first routine running, and process new data as it comes in?

Comment: the poll() function polls an updating config file, then create function creates news objects from this config that it continually refreshes. When the config changes, I don't need the old objects to keep being refreshed. If you know a good go way to do this, I'm all ears :) @EliasVanOotegem

Comment: @testing495 I've posted an answer with 3 options. The last one is how I'd go about it. Because it uses a loop (`for nbp := range ch`), the old maps are not kept in memory anyway, and there's no need for a channel that uses a `bool` (which really should be `struct{}` as it's a 0-bytes type).

Comment: @EliasVanOotegem thanks, I'm just trying your suggestions out :)

Comment: @testing495 wrote that off the top of my head, so there might be some typo's and the like, but the concept should be clear. IDK if your config changes are file-based, but if they are, there's plenty of packages that tap into the filesystem to notify you of changes to files to reload config (e.g. github.com/fsnotify/fsnotify). That might be worth a look, too. The code you provided also has no way to cleanly exit/terminate in case the application shuts down. You may want to use a `context.WithCancel` for that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A simple workaround looks like this

```golang
package main

func Start() {
    go func() {
        var i int
        quit := make(chan bool)
        for nbp := range poll() {
            if i > 0 {
                quit <- true
            }
            i++
            go create(nbp, quit)
        }
    }()
}

func create(nbp map[string]string, quit chan bool) {
    for {
        select {
        case <-quit:
            fmt.Println("quiting this goroutine!")
            return
        default:
            for k, v := range nbp {
            //...
            }
            time.Sleep(3 * time.Second)
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

So looking at the code you provided, you're wanting to spin up a new routine every time `poll` provides new data. That's trivial to do:

```
func Start() {
    for nbp := range poll() {
        go create(nbp)
    }
}

func create(nbp map[string]string) {
    // do stuff here
}
```

OK, but with this approach, you might be spawning a ton of routines at the same time. The `quit` channel you're using suggests you only want to spawn a new routine after the previous one has finished. Again, this is trivial to achieve:

```
func Start() {
    ch := make(chan struct{}) // struct{} is 0 bytes in size as per spec
    defer close(ch) // close channel when done
    for nbp := range poll() {
        go create(nbp, ch)
        ch <- struct{}{} // blocks until the routine has read from the channel
    }
}

func create(nbp map[string]string, ch <-chan struct{}) {
    for k, v := range nbp {
        // ... do stuff
    }
    time.Sleep(3 * time.Second)
    <-ch // read to unblock Start
}
```

Great, but now we're just doing things in sequence, and using a pretty pointless channel to do so... Why not simply do this:

```
func Start() {
    ch := make(chan map[string]string) // data in the channel
    defer close(ch) // close channel when done
    go create(ch) // start the routine reading data from the channel
    for nbp := range poll() {
        ch <- nbp // put data on channel, blocks until routine reads from the channel
        time.Sleep(3 * time.Second) // sleep here
    }
}

func create(nbp <-chan map[string]string) {
    for nbp := range ch { // read from channel
        // and process sequentially
        for k, v := range nbp {
            // ... do stuff
        }
    }
}
```

The reason why I moved the sleep to the loop that writes to the channel is because on the first iteration, the routine will immediately read from the channel (it's not doing anything yet), and unblock the `poll()` loop. That'll result in 2 calls to `poll()` in quick succession. Moving the sleep out of the routine ensures that you'll have at least 3 seconds in between the first and second call. After that, the behaviour is pretty much identical. I say pretty much, because you're not *"bothering"* the runtime and scheduler as much in order to release resources associated with the `create` routine every time, and scheduling a new routine immediately after.

Comment: So an issue I'm having with running this is that the body of crate doesn't run in a forever loop, and therefore isn't repeating the ...do stuff functionality to the new configs that have been read. I'm currently trying to see if I can add forever loops in myself

Comment: @testing495 Well, having not seen what you do in the `for k, v := range nbp` loop, I don't know precisely what the issue is there. The `create` function does run forever in the snippet I provided (or at least: until the channel is closed)...

Comment: The value of v fetches an ETag. This needs to be done every 3 seconds, however in your code, I believe it only fetches the ETag once

Comment: @testing495 You'd have to show how you're fetching it. I've mocked something I think resembles your setup [here](https://play.golang.org/p/ROvxLIwaD1f), and all values are coming through nicely. I must say: if `poll()` does in fact return a channel like I think it does, I'd probably not even bother wrapping it in a `Start` function, but instead just call `poll()` directly from my `create` routine